# Selenium Webdriver Import ChromeDriverManager Error

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using selenium webdriver; however, I am now attempting to interact with a page using Java (this is new to me).  In attempting to do this, I've found this video that appears to be exactly what Im looking for:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBRFVIEiFIE

I keep getting an error message generated from the second line of the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

This is the error  message:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\erich\Desktop\SeleniumDrivers\State Scrape Java.py", line 2, in <module>
 from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 4, in <module>
 from webdriver_manager.driver import ChromeDriver
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\driver.py", line 77
 self.auth_header = {'Authorization': f'token {self._os_token}'}
                                                             ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have made sure to pip install webdriver-manager and have attempted the two possible options on pypi.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#selenium4 with python [pip install selenium4)

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

#options to add as arguments
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("start-maximized")

#chrome to stay open
option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=option)
driver.get('https://www.example.com/')
```

[WebdriverManager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Comment: I didn't realize there a pip for selenium 3 and 4.  Got this installed, and everything worked like a charm.  Thank you!